# How to make Laravel Session Array Push?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to keep the records added in the last 20 seconds in the session. I check this with Ajax. But the most recent record is constantly being added. I can't write on it. I'm trying session :: pull this time, {} sounds empty this way.

Here is the sample code;

```
$crm = \GuzzleHttp\json_decode($guzzle->getBody()->getContents(), true);

foreach($crm['list'] as $row) {
      if(Carbon::create($row['createdAt'])->add(2, 'minutes')->diffInSeconds() < 20) {
             Session::put('data', [$row]);
       }
 }

 return response()->json(Session::get('data'));
```

Comment: Why you're putting it in session? Can't you store it in array?

Comment: I understand, but after 20 seconds, the array is empty. I want to keep it. That's why I use session. @DilipHirapara

Answer (score 0):

Define array and send it into JSON instead of using the session.

```
$data = array();
foreach($crm['list'] as $row) {
      if(Carbon::create($row['createdAt'])->add(2, 'minutes')->diffInSeconds() < 20) {
             $data[] =  $row;
       }
 }

 return response()->json($data);
```

Comment: I understand, but after 20 seconds, the array is empty. I want to keep it. That's why I use session.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Session::put` you are overriding that key in the session, so you will always end up with the last record in a single-item array in the session.

If you want to keep all the entries in the session, you should prepare the data, and then put it in the session.

```
$data = [];

foreach($crm['list'] as $row) {
    if (Carbon::create($row['createdAt'])->add(2, 'minutes')->diffInSeconds() < 20) {
        $data[] =  $row;
    }
}

Session::put('data', $data);

return response()->json($data);
```

**About using session**

As Dilip Hirapara suggested, if you aren't using this information in another place, you may not need to rely on session, and just return an array.

Comment: I understand, but after 20 seconds, the array is empty. I want to keep it. That's why I use session.